# How do I create an iterable of set length using the minimal amount of memory?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a task that includes sending out a bunch of requests to the same end point in quick succession a set number of times (the number exact number is not critically important if that would change anything) and I am using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent futures.

The issue when I try to call the ThreadPoolExecutor.map function like below:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.map(function_to_call, dummy_iterable)
```

I could of course create something like this:

```
dummy_iterable = [""] * 50
```

But I am wondering what preferred method would be in a case like this? The goal being to make the ThreadPoolExecutor call a function that needs no input argument a set number of times.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered generators?

Comment: `range(50)` seems to work fine; it's iterable and optimized for use in loops already.

Comment: I did consider generators, not sure how to properly implement it in this case. range(50) works but I wonder if its any better than [""] * 50? it certainly looks cleaner if nothing else

Comment: `range` takes O(1) memory. But this seems like an XY problem; if the contents of the iterable don't actually matter to you then `map` is the wrong thing to use. It seems like what you actually want to do is just call the function 50 times from different threads, is that correct?

Comment: correct, I guess switching over the submit rather than map is the right call?